# How to access element in a local DOM if id has dash?

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
<dom-module id="name-tag">
  <template>
    <div id="offices-list"></div>
  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer({
    is: "name-tag",
    ready: function() {
      var div_new = document.createElement('div');
      Polymer.dom(this.$.officesList).appendChild(div_new);
    }
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This currently gives an error:

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on
>   'Node': Only one element on document allowed.

However if I changed id from "offices-list" to "officesList", it works. How can I do the same thing keeping the id as it is, i.e. with dash?

Comment: why does your id not have quotes

Comment: What version of Polymer are  you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an open issue/enhancement with Polymer:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1747 also https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/150

Work around is to use `this.$['offices-list']`